# Can I limit users to VDI

Tags: windows, security, vdi, restrictions, vmware-horizon-view

I have a task to enable users to only access VDI(horizon view) when they login to their laptop or desktop.
This should restrict then from any other actions than accessing the view application.

Basically I want to implement a desktop security model.

I need suggestions what's the right approach for securing the data considering I want data at rest not to go out is the organization.

PS I don't have a dlp solution.

Comment: Just deny the execution of any other process than the view client?